# Angular best practice with Observable Value changes

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, observable

in our current project we use a Observable and if the value changes we have to make other api calls. For example something like this (`authorizedModules$` is a Observable):

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authorizedModules$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
        switchMap(async () => this.load())
      ).subscribe();
}

async load(): Promise<void> {
    const foo: boolean = await this.fooService.isFoo().toPromise();
    
    if (!foo) {
      return;
    }
    
    const fooA: Foo[] = await this.authorizedModules$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
    
    if (!fooA || fooA.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    
    this.fooB = await this.fooService.getFoo(fooA);
    ....  
}
```

I'm not sure if this an anti pattern or at least a good solution, because we mix Observables and Promises.
So what would be the best way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there's no need to convert the observables to promises. You could map from one observable to another using a higher order mapping operator (like `concatMap`) and use `filter` operator to proceed only when specific conditions are met.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.authorizedModules$.pipe(
    concatMap(() => this.fooService.isFoo()),
    filter(foo => !!foo),
    concatMap(() => this.authorizedModules$.pipe(take(1))),
    filter(fooA => !!fooA && fooA.length != 0),
    concatMap(fooA => this.fooService.getFoo(fooA)),
    takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
  ).subscribe({
    next: (res: any) => {
      // handle response
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle error
    }
  });
}
```